# How many user code snippets does Xcode (9 or any version) support? Unlimited, or a fixed number?

Tags: xcode9, xcode10

I've found Xcode feature to create user code snippets to be extremely useful. Just wondering how many user snippets it can handle.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode **user code snippets** are saved in the local disk, so as much as you want until you run out of your disk space.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Sure my pleasure